# Finding three integers such that their sum of cosine values become max

Tags: python, optimization, numbers, combinations, mathematical-optimization

There are three integers `x`, `y` and `z` (each of them >= 1) and a given upper bound integer `n` < 10^6. Also, `n = x + y + z` and `output = cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z)`.

The exercise is to maximize `output`.

I wrote a simple script for this, but the time complexity is O(n^3). Is there any way to simplify this?

```
from math import cos

n = 50
x = 1
y = 1
z = 1

total = cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z)

for x in xrange(n):
    for y in xrange(n):
        for z in xrange(n):
            if x + y + z == n:
                temp = cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z)
                if temp > total: total = temp

print round(total, 9)
```

Comment: lookup knapsack algorithm. Basically the hard part is to avoid to test x+y+z if you're sure they won't match n because too big.

Comment: dynamic programming algorithm, involves computing partial sums, sorting results, and bisection algortithm to find the answer. The cosines are there to introduce some "randomness" in the results. Interesting "project euler" like problem

Comment: I think you don't mean "simplify" but "make it run faster".

Comment: What's the correct result for `x`, `y` and `z`?

Comment: Presumably you mean three _unique_ integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally, you want to calculate each possible combination only once. Ignoring the geometric properties of `cos`, and treating it as simply some mapping from number to number (e.g. using it as a random property, as @Jean mentioned in his second comment). 
First, you must realize that after picking 2 numbers, the third is given. and you can pick 'smart' to avoid redundant picks:

```
from math import cos
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit



def calc(n):
    x = 1
    y = 1
    z = 1
    total = cos(x) + cos(y) + cos(z)
    for x in range(n, int((n/3 - 1)),-1): #I only want to pick X from n-2 to  n/3 -1 , after that we will repeat.
        cosx = cos(x)
        for y in range(max(int(((n-x)/2))-1,1),min(int(n-x),int(n/3))): #I would only pick number that will not be choosen for the z
                z = n-x-y #Infer the z, taking the rest in account
                temp = cosx + cos(y) + cos(z)
                if temp > total: total = temp
    return total

tic = time.clock()
total = calc(10000)
print(time.clock()-tic)

print (total)
```

Will take `1.3467099999999999` (on my machine).
And as @fuglede mentioned, it is worth using numba for further optimizing.

**Edit:**
Saving all the previously calculated cos values is actuallty more expensive then recalculating them, when you access np array you are not simply accessing a point in memory,but using an ndarray function. Using python built-in `cos` is actually faster:

```
import numpy as np

from math import cos
import time
import timeit

cos_arr = np.cos(np.arange(10000000))
tic = time.time()

def calc1():
    total = 0
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range(10000000):
            total += cos_arr[i]

def calc2():
    total = 0
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range(10000000):
            total += cos(i)

time1 = timeit.Timer(calc1).timeit(number=1)

time2 = timeit.Timer(calc2).timeit(number=1)
print(time1)
print(time2)
```

With output:

```
127.9849290860002
108.21062094399986
```

If i move the array creation inside the timer, its even slower.

Comment: Any answer that calls `cos(x)` more than once for each `x` deserves a downvote.

Comment: Python built-in cos is faster then np array access, so you are actually wrong. Added code to demonstrate it.

Comment: You don't need an array access. You just set `cosx = `cos(x)` after the first `for`-statement, and use that instead of `cos(x)`. Try it and see.

Comment: Yes you are right, had some bias regarding what you meant, so gave the wrong meaning to your comment. I was aiming just to reduce the O, and both (re-evaluating and saving it) are both O(1), but you are correct, and its redundant, fixed it.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the improvements you mention: Testing with N = 10^5 and using the IPython `%timeit` magic, looking up `cos[a]` in the inner loop rather than once outside is slightly *faster*.  At the same time, not precomputing the values of cos makes the thing drastically *slower*: On my machine, with N = 10^4, the precomputed version takes 1.55s to execute whereas calculating them each time takes 16.4 ms, while calculating cos in the inner loop takes 388 ms. The ratio between the two grows with N. Your test case is probably two small to capture the benefits of lookups properly.

Comment: Updated with a bigger `N` test case, still the same result. or is the `N` isn't big enough yet?

Comment: Your welcome to try it out yourself: https://repl.it/repls/WellgroomedBestCharacterencoding

Comment: @Dinari Thanks for spelling that out; I was comparing to `np.cos` instead of `cos`, and indeed `cos` is faster. Nevertheless, I'm still seeing huge benefits for caching when running a piece of code closer to what OP is interested in; i.e. loops over ranges of same order of magnitude, and sums of three cosines rather than a single one. That is, in https://repl.it/repls/RemoteVitalFlashmemory `cos` has the edge when N = 1000, but once you increase `N` to 10000, the lookup method is faster.

Comment: That is actually due to the `Jit` optimization. remove it and the `cos` version is faster.

Comment: It definitely helps. I don't have the machine to see how the two compare all the way to N = 10^6 without JIT compilation though.

Comment: Running it for assorted values between 10000 and 100000 does make it seem consistent; kind of makes sense given the double dereference.

Answer (score 13):

As pointed out by Jean-François Fabre in the comments, there are plenty of tricks you could apply to improve performance, but by first of all

- noting that the values of `a` and `b` determine the value of `c`,
- noting that at least one of the three variables, WLOG `a`, is less than or equal to `N/3`,
- using the remaining symmetry in `b` and `c` to bound `b` between `a` and `(N - a)//2 + 1`
- precomputing all relevant values of cos, and trying to avoid looking up the same values in rapid succession,
- pruning the outer loop to stop early when a given value of `cos(a)` can never lead to a new maximum,
- using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to JIT-compile the code and get some performance for free (about a factor of 400 for `N = 500`),

then the otherwise bruteforcy solution terminates relatively quickly for `N = 1000000`:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit
def maximize(N):
    cos = np.cos(np.arange(N))
    m = -3
    for a in range(1, N//3 + 1):
        cosa = cos[a]
        if m - 2 > cosa:
            continue
        for b in range(a, (N - a)//2 + 1):
            c = N - a - b
            res = cosa + cos[b] + cos[c]
            if res > m:
                m = res
                bestabc = (a, b, c)
    return m, bestabc

maximize(1000000)  # (2.9787165245899025, (159775, 263768, 576457))
```

It's worth noting that the symmetry exploited above only holds so far as one is willing to ignore the fact that numerical issues cause addition of floating-point numbers not to be commutative in general; that is `cos(a) + cos(b)` need not be the same as `cos(b) + cos(a)`. Chances are that you won't worry about that though.

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no need to calculate 3 x n^3 cosine values.

We can assume that x ≤ y ≤ z. Therefore x can be any integer in the range from 1 to n/3. y can be any integer in the range from x to (n - x) / 2. And z must be equal to n - x - y. This alone reduces the number of triples (x, y, z) that you try out from n^3 to about n^2 / 6.

Next assume that you found three numbers with a total of 2.749. And you try an x with cosine (x) = 0.748. Any total involving this x cannot be more than 2.748, so you can reject x outright. Once you found one good sum, you can reject many values of x.

To make this more effective, you sort the values x from highest to lowest value of cosine(x), because that makes it more likely you find a high total which allows you to remove more values.

And calculating cos(x) is slow, so you store the values into a table.

So:

```
Set c[i] = cos (i) for 1 ≤ i ≤ n. 
Set x[i] = integers 1 to n/3, sorted in descending order by value of c[i]. 
Set (bestx, besty, bestz) = (1, 1, n-2) and total = c[bestx] + c [besty] + c [bestz].

for x = elements of array x where c[x] + 2 ≥ bestTotal
    for y = x to (n-x)/2
        z = n - x - y
        total = c[x] + c[]y] + c[z]
        if total > bestTotal
            (bestx, besty, bestz) = (x, y, z)
            bestTotal = total
```

You can improve on this with a bit of maths. If the sum of y + z is constant, like here where y + z = n - x, the sum of cos(y) + cos (z) is limited. Let P be the integer closest to (n - x) / 2pi, and let d  = (n - x) - P * 2pi, then the largest possible sum of cos (y) + cos (z) is 2 * cos (d/2).

So for every x, 1 ≤ x ≤ n/3, we calculate this value d and cos (x) + 2 * cos (d/2), store these values as the maximum total that can be achieved with some x, sort x so that these values will be in descending order, and ignore those x where the achievable total is less than the best total so far.

If n is really large (say a billion), then you can use Euclid's algorithm to find all integers y that are close to 2k*pi + d quickly, but that will be a bit complicated.

```
for x in 1 to n/3
    let s = n - x
    let P = s / 2pi, rounded to the nearest integer
    let d = (s - P * 2pi) / 2
    let maxSum [x] = cos(x) + 2*cos(d)

Set x[i] = integers 1 to n/3, sorted in descending order by value of maxSum[i]. 
Set (bestx, besty, bestz) = (1, 1, n-2)
Set bestTotal = c[bestx] + c [besty] + c [bestz].

for x = elements of array x where maxSum[x] ≥ bestTotal
    for y = x to (n-x)/2
        z = n - x - y
        total = c[x] + c[]y] + c[z]
        if total > bestTotal
            (bestx, besty, bestz) = (x, y, z)
            bestTotal = total
```

PS. I actually tried this for some values of N around 100 million. It turns out, I can either sort the array to try the most promising values for x first, which takes a long time, but often the first value for x is the only one that gets tried. Or I can use x = 1, 2, 3 etc. which means a few dozens values for x will be tried, which is faster than sorting.

Comment: " z must be equal to n - x - y.". True, but n is mostly unknown (it's only restricted to <1.000.000).

Answer (score 1):

No need to ever compute a cosine to answer this question. Just keep track of the three (two if n=0 is allowed) smallest values of function 
`f(n) = abs(2pi*n-round(2pi*n))` 
as `n` goes from 1 to N, where N is your upper limit of search.

Cosine is 1 at multiples of `2*pi` so we search for the two or three multiples closest to an integer within the search limit.

Haven't run a program to do this yet, but it should be easy in any programming langauage. I will use Mathematica.

Answer (score -1):

This is purely a basic trigonometry problem. The max value for your equation will be when all the cosine's each have a value of 1. In cos(n), where n is any number, for all the values formed by the set of n = 2 * pi * k, where k >= 0 and k is an integer; your cosine will have a value of 1. Your x, y, z values belong in this set and the permutation of these values will get you your desired value.
Also, don't forget to check whether n in the set is an integer to reduce the sample space.

Comment: Such numbers would be irrational while all @barbossa's inputs are rational.

Comment: 0 is a rational number as far as I know, so the complexity of the problem is now reduced to O(1). I edited my answer.

Comment: The inputs are assumed to be positive.

Comment: @S.Patel since x, y, and z are positive integers, there are no solutions for finite `n` which give you cosines of 1.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. Let n = 3, then your only choice is x = y = z = 1, and the total is 3 * cos(1) ≈ 1.62. Let n = 5 and the best solution is x = y = 1, z = 3 with a total about 0.09.